# Application Lifecycle Management -VS- Software Development Lifecycle?

Tags: alm, sdlc

What is the difference between Application Lifecycle Management and Software Development Lifecycle?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a link to a blog post that describes it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisbirmele/archive/2007/04/23/alm-versus-sdlc-two-different-things.aspx

An excerpt from it that explicitly answers your question:

"**Software Development Life Cycle;**  this includes everything to do with DEVELOPING a software application, including requirements, architecture, coding, testing, configuration management project management

**Application Life Cycle Management;**  as the name suggests includes everything that is part of the Application Lifecycle.  When does the life of an apps start?  No, not in development, it starts somewhere in the business as an idea, a need, a challenge, a risk.  When does the life of an application end?  No, not at the end of development, but when the application is no longer used by the business - potentially many years after the initial development."